# How to declare Type for a params list of lambda expressions?

Tags: c#, generics, lambda

I'm trying to build a method which takes a `params` list (*i.e.*, a comma-separated list) of lambda expressions.

```
public void DoSomething<TDataType, ...>(params Expression<Func<TDataType, TNavProp>>[] properties)
{
    // ...
}
```

How can I declare `TNavProp` in a way which allows multiple different types?

For example...

```
public class Class1
{
    public int IntProp { get; set;}

    public string StringProp { get; set; }
}

DoSomething<Class1, int>(cl => cl.IntProp);    // this compiles
DoSomething<Class1, ?>(cl => cl.IntProp, cl => cl.StringProp);    // this won't compile
```

Is the only solution to declare multiple overloads of `DoSomething`, each with successively more expression arguments?

Inside the method, I actually only want to record the `PropertyInfo` (I would even settle for the property name, as a last resort), so is there a simpler way of achieving that?

Comment: Even if you could, how would you use those expressions?

Comment: By inspecting the `Body` for each expression, I can determine the name and type of each property. As I write at the end of the OP, I really just want to keep track of the properties, whether it's by `PropertyInfo` or even just the name.

Comment: You could try using dynamic: public void DoSomething<TDataType>(params Expression<Func<TDataType, dynamic>>[] properties) this way you don't need the second generic argument.

Comment: just call your method like this: ``DoSomething<Product, dynamic>(cl => cl.Category, cl => cl.Name);``

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay If you write your last comment as an answer, I'll mark as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, because you simply need the `PropertyInfo` related to each expression, and the return type is not a concern, you can use `object` as your `TReturn`:

```
public static void DoSomething<TDataType>(
    params Expression<Func<TDataType, object>>[] properties)
```

Now this is valid, because each lambda can be converted into a `Expression<Func<Class1, object>>`:

```
DoSomething<Class1>(cl => cl.IntProp, cl => cl.StringProp);
```